# Tree View structure in web form using Django

Tags: django

I want to create a webform in Tree view using Django. I am completely new to it and could not able to understand how to make it.

I tried the following code in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
ul, #myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tree View</h2>
<p>A tree view represents a hierarchical view of information, where each item can have a number of subitems.</p>
<p>Click on the arrow(s) to open or close the tree branches.</p>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret">Beverages</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

but how to make it in Django? need to represent the same. Tried some github examples but couldn't succeed in getting. can someone suggest me a simple example

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use a framework like semantic-UI or bootstrap. it will be easier. 
In your case, you can replace any `<ul>` with `<form>`. after that to be more realistic and more sense you can use ajax to submit a form without reloading the page. the idea here not in Django itself the problem is how to do that in HTML, CSS, and JS. if you do that with them Django side will be easy.